# angular name router-outlet lazyload Error: Cannot match

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular-module

My Route of the Root Module is like this:
http://localhost:4200/#/booking/flightBooking/list

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FlightBookingListComponent } from './flight-booking-list.component';
import { ItineraryBookingDetailModule } from '../../itinerary/booking-detail/itinerary-booking-detail.module';
import { LazyloadModalComponent } from 'app/shared/lazyload-modal/lazyload-modal.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: FlightBookingListComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'itinerary',
        outlet: 'modal',
        component: LazyloadModalComponent,
        children: [
          {path: '', loadChildren: '../../itinerary/booking-detail/itinerary-booking-detail.module#ItineraryBookingDetailModule'}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'itinerary',
    outlet: 'modal',
    component: LazyloadModalComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', loadChildren: '../../itinerary/booking-detail/itinerary-booking-detail.module#ItineraryBookingDetailModule'}
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FlightBookingListRoutingModule { }
```

html code

```
...list
    <div><router-outlet name="modal"></router-outlet></div>
```

component.ts

```
onClickDetail(rowItem: any): void {
    console.log(this.router)
    console.log(this.activatedRoute)
    console.log(rowItem)
    console.log(ITEM.CATEGORY_CODE.FLIGHT)
    // this.router.navigate(['itinerary', {
    //   categotyCode: ITEM.CATEGORY_CODE.FLIGHT,
    //   bookingCode: rowItem.bookingItemCode
    // }])

    this.router.navigate(
      ['', {outlets: {modal: ['itinerary']}}],
      // {
      //   relativeTo: this.activatedRoute
      // }
    );

    // this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { modal: ['itinerary'] } }]);

    // this.router.navigate([{ outlets: {
    //   modal: ['itinerary']
    // }}]);
  }
```

error img

NavigationError {id: 2, url: "/booking/flightBooking/list(modal:itinerary)"

Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'itinerary'